# The right way to arrange the basic operators in RxJava

Tags: exception, rx-java

```
   mSubscriptions.add(api.signIn(phoneNumber, otp)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .doOnError(throwable -> Timber.e(throwable.getMessage()))
        .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> Observable.empty())
        .subscribe(user -> {
          // Handle user object logic here
          }
        }));
```

I generally use this pattern in all my apps for the schedulers and to handle exceptions, but sometimes i get an illegal state exceptions like this : Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread. Add `onError` handling. Caused by rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException, so i was wondering if this is right. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @yosriz mentioned - the *right* way is to implement `onError` callback in every subscriber. In your case, you're getting `OnErrorNotImplementedException` most likely due to your *"Handle user object logic"* throws.

**Simple examples:**

*Exception in the stream:*

```
Observable.just("value")
    .flatMap(s -> Observable.error(new IllegalStateException()))
    .onErrorResumeNext(t -> Observable.empty())
    .doOnCompleted(() -> System.out.println("Completed"))
    .subscribe(s -> {});
```

> Completed

---

*Exception in onNext callback:*

```
Observable.just("value")
    .onErrorResumeNext(t -> Observable.empty())
    .doOnCompleted(() -> System.out.println("Completed"))
    .subscribe(s -> {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    });
```

> rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException
>   ...
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException

---

*Exception in onNext callback, subscriber's onError implemented:*

```
Observable.just("value")
    .onErrorResumeNext(t -> Observable.empty())
    .doOnCompleted(() -> System.out.println("Completed"))
    .subscribe(s -> {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }, t -> {
        System.out.println("Subscriber's onError triggered");
    });
```

> Subscriber's onError triggered

Answer (score 1):

Arranging Schedulers has nothing to do with this type of error you get. The problem can happen if you don't have `onError()` handling on your subscriber (at the `subscribe()` method), and you get error somewhere in the stream without any handling.
`doOnError()` will not solve this, as it's just a side effect operator that will perform some operation with any `onError()`.
In fact, In your example `onErrorResumeNext()` will handle the error as it will swallow any error, so probably you have other scenarios, where you do not handle all errors scenarios and thus got the on error not implemented exception.
As a general pattern, it's always better to prepared to any case and implement `onError()` at the subscriber to avoid cases where error was not handled down the stream.